# Angular CLI 6: background-image issue

Tags: angular, webpack, background-image, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

Angular CLI 6.0.3 resolves sass code `background-image: url(assert/folder1/x.png);` as `background-image: url(x.png);` in css.

I have a lot of such places

```
...
background-image: url(assert/folder1/x.png);
...
background-image: url(assert/folder2/x.png);
...
background-image: url(assert/folder3/x.png);
...
```

But all these definitions become to be like

```
...
background-image: url(x.png);
...
background-image: url(x.png);
...
background-image: url(x.png);
...
```

It means that all classes have the same image...

How can I force Angular CLI to leave a path of an image?

**UPD: the issue effects only for dev mode**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add "**outputHashing**" property with "**media**" value.

```
/* angular.json */
{
  ...
  "projects": {
     ...
     "your-project": {
        ...
        "architect": {
           ...
           "build": {
             ...
             "options": {
                ...
                "outputHashing": "media",
                ...
             }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, you can use only background: url() in stead of background-image: url() `background: url('/assets/images/gc1.jpg')`